Could Kubernetes' egress be the cause of the 503 UC error?
When using istio's egress gateway, if there is no separate setting, will the network timeout settings of envoy be used as is?
ex) idle timeout -> 1hour
Then, when outbound traffic is generated through egress, I am curious whether temporary port depletion of egress or maintenance of disconnected connections may occur due to the keepalive timeout or connection timeout settings of the destination server.
The reason I'm asking this question is, we migrated a server to a k8s environment.
After that, when we call API request from our server to the destination server, we intermittently received a 503 UC error. But the destination server said that it could not confirm the request.
Due to the overall structure, only egress, which is responsible for outbound traffic, was added, but it is doubtful that this is the start of the issue.

A direct quote from the [tag:kubernetes] tag wiki: KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT. Configuration and deployment is off-topic here..

@SaiChandiniRouthu Your answer was useful. Our team is conducting several checks based on the answers you gave. We hope the problem will be resolved and we are seeing some pretty good results. Thank you.

Both for upstream and downstream connections if there is no specific idleTimeout is specified then the default value is 1 hour.  This is applicable for TCP and HTTP as well.  More details of TCP and HTTP settings are mentioned in the documentation.  This setting of idleTimeout can be overridden by mentioning the required value in istio destination rule, below is the sample for tcp.
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-redis
spec:
  host: myredissrv.prod.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    connectionPool:
      tcp:
        idleTimeout: 10s

